# Sonatype Nexus local install, new versions not showing in pom.xml

Tags: maven, pom.xml, sonatype

I have a local Sonatype nexus install that I use to host some .jar files, and I'm trying to get those in my maven project.

Per sonatype, this is my repo

[image: Repo per sonatype]

And this is how I have the repo in my pom.xml file

[image: pom.xml repo]

And here are the artifacts I have in the repo

[image: repo artifacts]

But my dependencies just aren't seeing them.  it doesn't see the work.torp one at all, and it doesn't see the most recent copy of internal (1.0.12)

[image: dependencies]

But does show up to 1.0.3

[image: versions]

I have tried clean installs, closing and reopening, rebuilding the index, invalidating caches etc.  Nothing seems to stick.

Is there something obvious I'm doing wrong?